# when I first push an existing repository from the command line

Tags: git, github

first `git remote add origin git@github.com:username/learngit.git` shows  `remote origin already exists`
then `git push -u origin master` shows that

```
ssh:connect to host git.com port 22:Connection timed out
fatal:Could not read from remote repository
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists
```

Comment: can you please give more information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> remote origin already exists

It means exactly that. You've previously added a remote, so it's stuck on the previous one.

> it shows that ssh:connect to host git.com port 22

This suggests that you made a typo and used `git.com` instead of `github.com`.

Remove your existing remote with `git remote rm origin`, then try adding the proper one and pushing again.